# Using ray on Databricks I got error ArrowInvalid: URI has empty scheme: '~/ray_results'

Tags: databricks, ray, pycaret

On a databricks notebook I'm running

```
%pip install jinja2 --upgrade
%pip install mlflow --upgrade
%pip install pycaret==3 catboost optuna lightgbm hyperopt tune-sklearn ray[tune]
%pip install pandas==1.4.0
```

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import mlflow
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from hyperopt import hp
from hyperopt.pyll.base import scope
from pycaret.classification.oop import ClassificationExperiment
```

```
space = {...
exp = ClassificationExperiment()
exp.setup(...
lgbm = exp.create_model("lightgbm", verbose=False)
sys.stdout.fileno = lambda: False
lgbm_ft = exp.tune_model(lgbm, ...
```

The resulting model seems to be created just fine, it appears on Experiments and it's possible to load id using mlflow, but exp.tune_model gets error
`ArrowInvalid: URI has empty scheme: '~/ray_results'`

Can anyone suggest where I should look at to debug this error?
Thanks.

PS
I read here https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/36949 that I should set RAY_AIR_NEW_OUTPUT=0

How do I do that?